# JS newbie confused about common test procedure

Tags: javascript, testing

All:

I have never done JS testing before, all I did is writting code, run it, if there is bug, figure out, if not, consider it as done.

For small projects, this is ok, cos I can figure out where is wrong quickly, but when I came to a team with medium size project, I realize I should learn how to do JS testing.

So my question is:

[1] Is there a common guideline about the procedures of testing(no need to cover everything, just from experienced engineer daily routine)? Like what to test and how. (some examples with explanation will be appreciated)

[2] I find most posts talking about using Jasmine/Mocha/Grunt/Karma to do test, but without understanding the content and plan, I do not quite understand why should I use them and how. So could anyone give me any example about their usage scene?

BTW, I know this is very newbie question, and probably someone will label this as too broad topic, if so, could you please just talk what you think from any specific point with small example. I will collect all the answers and make summary myself( the most important thing I need to know is what "specific" tests I "usually" need to do (Like: a test flow). As for how to do, that is second priority ).

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned Jasmine and Mocha by name (so you're aware of them) - but have you looked for and read any tutorials that explain how to use them to unit test your JS code? That's where I would start to gain an understanding of what you should be doing to test your JS code.

Comment: @jamauss Thanks, those Jasmine/Mocha... are just names to me for now.  Like I said, I am very newbie at the moment, so finding right entry in a document is kinda hard for me. What I have done by now is finding quick start tutorials to see how to use them, but even I go though most of those tutorials, I still feel I have no idea what I need to do with real project even I have those testing tool on hand. I kind need a guide to show me what to do after I write my code and how to use those tool to do that. I think there should be some systematic procedure to follow.

Comment: Unit testing is a *huge* subject, it's not like you can compress it to a couple of bullet points. It's like asking "what's the procedure to follow for programming." If you have no idea how unit testing works, you're getting ahead of yourself by studying the tools; you should start with the basics of testing itself first.

Comment: @Juhana Thanks so much, what you said is right on the point. My current situation is having no idea about unit test( I do not even know it is about unit testing) but only find posts about learning how to use those tools which makes myself ahead of. The thing you said "start with the basics of testing itself first" is exactly what I am looking for, but without any advise, I kinda confuse where to start to learn basic rule and method in testing :(

Answer (score 2):

what you need to test depends on your application. The most easy thing to start with are unit tests. Here you test single functions or objects. Write your test code in a way it can be run again and again. If you have objects that call other objects as well, you might add a dummy implementation here. You can do this by Hand or use a Mock JavaScript framework. A good unit test

- is repeatable
- does not depends on external data
- test only one Funktionalität at a time

Automation is where grunt and jasmine help you.
Grunt is a build tool, like ant if you are familar with Java or Make in Linux. Grunt can use Jasmine to run your tests before every deployment.

For an introduction of the general theory take a look at the article about test driven development at the wikipedia  here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development. Also the book *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin has a good Paragraph about TDD.

I hope I could help you a little bit.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. I will find those posts and book see if I can figure out any. And also could you give me a concrete example to follow, so I can get a general idea what it looks like?